# openfile dialog cancel crash

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am making a basic word processor in c# for training. Now I am making the open file part of it. I can open a text file without issue. But when I open the open file dialog and then cancel it, it crashes :/

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    var OpenFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    getRichTextBox().Text = OpenFile.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I know it is because the streamreader has nothing to read but I am not sure how to solve this.

thanks in advance!

Edit: Thank you! it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to check the result of the dialog:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        using (var openFile = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
            getRichTextBox().Text = OpenFile.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

I've also added a `using` statement to ensure that your file is closed when you're done reading it.

You can simplify the code even further by simply using [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) instead of messing around with `StreamReader`.

```
getRichTextBox().Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

(Thanks @keyboardP)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var OpenFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    getRichTextBox().Text = OpenFile.ReadToEnd();
}
```